# How to integrate Firebase in ios app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-invites

I want to integrate my app through firebase I follow this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/ios but it shows me error of user must be sign in.

AppDeleget :

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return self.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: "")
    }

    internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {


        if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) {
            return true
        }

        return Invites.handleUniversalLink(url) { invite, error in
            // ...
        }

         return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

My InviteVC

```
@IBAction func BtnActionInvtation(_ sender: Any) {

    if let invite = Invites.inviteDialog() {
        invite.setInviteDelegate(self)

        invite.setMessage("Try this app")
        // Title for the dialog, this is what the user sees before sending the invites.
        invite.setTitle("Invites Example")
        invite.setDeepLink("app_url")
        invite.setCallToActionText("Install!")
        invite.setCustomImage("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")
        invite.open()
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I put code there

Comment: "Failed: User must be signed in before launching the Invite Widget." i getting this error

Comment: It tells you in the documentation I linked you yesterday how to implement the sign in - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Comment: so i must be sign-in for invite ?

Comment: ok get it thanks a lot sir

Comment: The solution was already been provided by firebase docs

Answer (score 2):

Change the rules in Firebase database rules if you are not asking user to sign in

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has clearly explained all the steps to integrate FirebaseInvites in iOS. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/

I think you don't read their documentation clearly. THey have mentioned you must sign in with Google account to invites your friends using FirebaseInvites.

If you need any help, please let me know.

Thanks!